Not finding search term with square brackets in it
I have the following line in my file:
if (Infix[i] == '+' || Infix[i] == '-' || Infix[i] == '/' || Infix[i] == '*')

When I search using the command /Infix[i] I am getting the error:
E486: Pattern not found: Infix[i]


You need to search for /Infix\[i].
This is because Vim searches using regular expressions.
Square brackets have a special meaning, they are a collection and will match any of the characters inside the brackets (which, in this case, is just the i) but not the brackets themselves.
To tell Vim not to use a collection but a literal bracket, you need to escape it with a backslash: /Infix\[i]
Another alternative when you have several special regex characters in your search pattern and you don't want to escape them all is to use either the nomagic or very nomagic modifiers \M or \V, respectively. The search would look like this: /\VInfix[i]
You can read all about regular expressions in the built-in help with :help pattern and about collections with :help /[].
Magic is documented in :help /magic.
A very useful option when it comes to searching is :set incsearch which will highlight your search results while you type.
In your case, Infix would be highlighted but as soon as you type the opening bracket [, the highlight will be gone, signifying that you did something wrong.
See :help 'incsearch'.

I think you meant 'incsearch' setting, to highlight while typing. 'hlsearch' does highlight after pressing enter. Also I think to search literal, using /\V may be a viable alternative

@ChristianBrabandt yep, I mixed incsearch up with hlsearch. Thank you for spotting my mistake. I'll give it another edit to also include /\V as you suggested.
